# How do I use information from my javascript (const) to insert into my html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I have this script:

```
const BusInfo = [
    {
        code: "B31",
        destination: "Toronto"
    },
    {
        code: "HJ1",
        destination: "Montreal"
    }
]
```

How would I be able to put that information in my html document? I cannot change the above script at all. I am having issue doing this, I have tried googling but there isn't much information on how to do that or I am just having trouble comprehending. Also, how would I be able to style this in css?

I have already called for the script in my index.html, but I am having trouble showing that information. One of the problems am having with is not being able to edit that script at all. I have to keep it like that.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents

Comment: Hi Parmingo, welcome to SO! What do you mean with ' I cannot change the above script at all'. The entire script incorporating the above code, or just the above code (being `BusInfo[..]`)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So you loop over the data and output it. If you need new elements, you build a string or you use createElement

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make some kind of project which will be using this kind of html manipulation a lot i would recommend you use a framework for that (react, vue, angular)

But if its just a one case scenario you can also do it with vanilla js using createElement:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Without more information on the code and what you are trying to achieve this is the best i can give you

Comment: Okay, thank you. I am trying to edit a main tag with the "container" class.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a paragraph:
`<p id="destination">Destination</p>`

You could do this to change the content of the paragraph:

```
document.querySelector('#destination').textContent = BusInfo.destination;
```

Comment: Would that go in the html file? I am not allowed to edit the javascript at all.